# Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

I have a string URL that includes UTF-8 characters, and I get this error when I use the `Volley` library:

> Unexpected response code 400 for [http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی](http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=%D9%85%D9%87%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B3%DB%8C) عمران&KEY=ایمنی ترافیک

What I think is this may not be read Complete, so I will not receive any replies from `onResponse`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: We need to see your code otherwise this becomes a guessing game for the community.  Please read the help section on how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Graham thank you, see my answer ... I solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to solve my problem. Share it, the main problem is due to the distance created by `String URL`. So, with the replacement order, the problem is resolved:

```
String URL;
String newString;
    URL= "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/search.php?Method=rate&CAT=مهندسی عمران&KEY=ایمنی ترافیک"
    newString = URL.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Happy Coding